# How to link a view output to its node?

Tags: views

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to link the whole view item output without modifying the template files. It is easy to link some fields to the node but I would like the whole view output to work as a link. Any suggestions?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by whole view output? The output of view are fields and you can link fields to node.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I mean the <div> that wraps all the fields. I'm using semantic Views and this <div> has a class of "view-myview-item".

Comment: you are not allowed to put a `<DIV>` in `<a>`!

Comment: It seems that it is allowed in HTML5: http://davidwalsh.name/html5-elements-links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily done by using the "**Content: Path**" and "**Global: Custom Text**" fields. See the following steps for details.

1. add a "Content: path" field
2. add a "Global: Custom text" field (make sure this is the last field)
3. exclude all fields from display except "Global: Custom Text" field
4. Use "Replacement Patterns" on "Text" inside the "Global: Custom text"
5. In Global: Custom text, check the "Output this field as a link" on rewrite results, and insert "**[path]**" on "Link path"

PS: "[path]" is link to the node

Comment: Worked like a charm, except for the fact that [path] contains only the URL alias, without the site base url, so I get link that don't work. If I choose "Use absolute path" option my links work, but contain two slashes. Ex.: www.mystie.com//mypath

Comment: You should check the "Use absolute path" on "Content: path" field, not "Global: Custom text".

Answer (score 0):

If yo don't want to modify the template file you may implement it using js, some thing like this,

```
$('.title-class').parent().parent().click(function(){
      var url = $(this).find(".title-class").attr('href');
      windows.location = url; 
});
```

BUT YOU MUST BE SURE THAT THE `DIV` DISPLAY MUST BE SET TO `INLINE-BLOCK` IN ORDER TO BE AS LARGE AS ITS CONTENT